# Can I add a "Save" / "Submit" button to a textfield so the text saves in the field when the button is clicked?

Tags: html, forms, button, submit, textfield

The title pretty much says it all.

Can I add a "Save" / "Submit" button to a textfield so the text saves in the field when the button is clicked?

I have a text field, but what I need now is to add a button to is so that when I am done writing in the text field the button "saves" the text that I wrote inside the text field.

I am not exactly sure how to do this and I have been searching for an answer forever now.
Any help would be appreciated.

My code currently looks like this, (obviously the Submit / Save button I added does nothing but refreshes the page and I lose all the text in the textfield)

```
<form class="admin-customer-notes">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" style="margin-bottom:30px; width: 100%; height: 200px;">
</textarea>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you want to save to? Do you have a server backend to submit data to?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an action to the form pointing to a server-side script using something like .PHP

Or, you may save the data using javascript/cookies.

Or you could use an AJAX call to a server-side script.

I'm not sure what scripting language you're familiar with, but if you do have access to PHP, here's what you can do ...

Change your form as follows:

```
<form class="admin-customer-notes" method="POST" action="/script.php">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" style="margin-bottom:30px; width: 100%; height: 200px;" name="text">
</textarea>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then in script.php you would parse the data and store it in whatever form you want.  For example:

script.php

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['text'];

// at this point, $text contains the text from the textarea.  You would need to write this to a database or a flat file.

?>
```

We can provide much better examples if you can tell us which scripting language you're using.  If you're only familiar with javascript, you may need to resort to cookies.

Comment: You can refer to this related post which shows a full PHP example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471448/how-to-save-the-data-that-the-user-input-in-form-page-after-the-script-executed

Comment: The only thing that sucks, is I only know html and css. I am not familiar with PHP or JS. Even though I would like to be more knowledgable in PHP and JS, I unfortunately have not had the time to study it and practice it.

EDIT: The reason I need this is because I run an online store, and I am trying to add a custom text field with a "Save" button. 
This text field will simply be used for notes pertaining to customers, it's just a reminded for myself and employees.

Comment: You could always have the user click an email link instead of using a form.  <a href="mailto:youremailaddress@here.now">Click Here to Send a Comment</a>.  The link will open their mail client and allow them to send you an email.  It's not the same as a form, but it would get the job done.

Comment: This is not for customers, this text field with the ability to keep the text purely on the text field, is strictly for admin use only. This is being applied to the admin backend on my website shopping cart "Magento" to be exact. So as soon as an admin logs in they see any message(s) another admin may have left for another employee. It's basically just a reminder for us admins and sort of a way to communicate with our products.

It would be very nice is when a new message in the text field was created, it automatically dated it and then dated it when it was resolved.
@luvnjesus